# SimpleXMLElement how to change tag content (value)

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I need to know how do I change content of the tag (not attributes, just content). I dont need inner tags inside this parent tag. I just need to put inside it some text. (Replace "1. Hello World") of the next xml file:

```
<config name="THIS" type="string">1. Hello World)</config>
<config name="IS" type="string">2. Hello World!</config>
<config name="SPARTA" type="string">3. Hello World?</config>
```

```
// create simple xml object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('file.xml'));

// new names and values
$names  = array('THIS', 'SPARTA');
$values = array('1. Good bye world(', '3. Good bye world?');

// replace here
foreach($xml as $a => $xmlElement) {
     $indexOfName = array_search($names, (string)$xmlElement['name']);
     if ($indexOfName !== false) {
          // here I need to replace the value (e.g. 1. Hello World)) of config
          // with the attribute @name == $names[$i] with the new value
          // $values[$i] (3. Good bye world?)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found temporary solution. Its to create a new simple xml and copy there all stuff from current simple xml with replacing content values

```
$newXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<' . $xml->getName() . '></' . $xml->getName() . '>');
foreach($xml as $a => $xmlElement) {
    $attr = $newXml->addChild($a, 'New content of the tag');
    foreach($xmlElement->attributes() as $k => $v) {
        $attr->addAttribute($k, $v);
    }
}
echo $newXml->asXML();
```

However its temporary. I hope if someone can produce more better solution

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you need the parent element or if you know the parents' structure you could try xpath. Other than that, you may want to try this hack:

```
$xmlElement->{0} = $values[$indexOfName];
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It didnt work